# Helm fails to add TLS in the GKE ingress

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-compute-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-controller

I'm trying to deploy the application in the GKE which contains ingress details

**values.yaml**

```
# Default values for test-frontend.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare variables to be passed into your templates.

global:
  namespace: isp

replicaCount: 2

image:
  repository: test.code.com/test/test-frontend
  pullPolicy: Always
  # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: ""

imagePullSecrets:
  - name: docker-cfg        
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: "test-frontend"

serviceAccount:
  # Specifies whether a service account should be created
  create: false
  # Annotations to add to the service account
  annotations: {}
  # The name of the service account to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name: "cloudsql-sa"

podAnnotations: {}

podSecurityContext: {}
  # fsGroup: 2000

securityContext: {}
  # capabilities:
  #   drop:
  #   - ALL
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  # runAsNonRoot: true
  # runAsUser: 1000

service:
  name: isp-stabsuite-frontend-service
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
  type: NodePort
  port: 80

resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 350m
    memory: 1000Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 250m
    memory: 750Mi

  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  # limits:
  #   cpu: 350m
  #   memory: 1000Mi
  # requests:
  #   cpu: 250m
  #   memory: 750Mi

autoscaling:
  enabled: false
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 100
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
  # targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 80

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}

#########Required Modifications###############

configmap:
  name: test-frontend-configmap
  env:
    GET_HOSTS_FROM: "dns"
    REACT_APP_BACKEND_API: "/api/v1"
    REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: ""
    APP_DB_CONNECTION_STRING: ""
    NODE_ENV: "production"
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.regional-static-ip-name : "ingress-internal-static-ip"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
  hosts:
    - host: test-sandbox.test.com
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        servicename: test-frontend-service
        serviceport: 80
      - path: "/api/"
        servicename: test-backend-service
        serviceport: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test-sandbox.test.com
    secretName: ingress-tls-credential-file 
    type: kubernetes.io/tls

#########Required Subchart Modifications###
isp-stabsuite-backend:
  cloudsqlConnection: ""
  cloudsqlproxySa: ""
  service:
    name: test-backend-service

  bigquerysecret:
    name: gcp-bigquery-credential-file
    type: Opaque
    content:
      credentials: test
```

**ingress-template file**

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.global.namespace }}-ingress
  namespace: {{ .Values.global.namespace }}
  labels:
    {{- include "test-frontend.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name : "ingress-internal-static-ip" 
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  {{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
     {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
     - hosts:
         {{- range .hosts }}
         - {{ . | quote }}
         {{- end }}
       secretName: {{ .secretName }}
     {{- end }}
  {{- end }} 
  rules:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
          {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ .path }}
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ .servicename }}
                port:
                  number: {{ .serviceport }}
          {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

When it tries to create ingress, it thows below error

> Error syncing to GCP: error running load balancer syncing routine:
> loadbalancer z30rnomw-isp-isp-ingress-pjgwvt2i does not exist: invalid
> configuration: both HTTP and HTTPS are disabled
> (kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http is false and there is no valid TLS
> configuration); your Ingress will not be able to serve any traffic

Even I cleanup the ingress and try to install fresh ingress it throws same error with same LoadBalancer ID (loadbalancer z30rnomw-isp-isp-ingress-pjgwvt2i)

```
kubectl describe ingress test-ingress -n test
Name:             test-ingress
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=test-frontend
                  app.kubernetes.io/type=frontend
                  app.kubernetes.io/version=1.16.0
                  helm/chart=test-frontend-0.1.0
Namespace:        isp
Address:
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host                         Path  Backends
  ----                         ----  --------
  test-sandbox.test.com
                               /       test-frontend-service:80 (xxx.xx.xxx.xx:80,xxx.xx.xxx.xx:80)
                               /api/   test-backend-service:80 (xxx.xx.xxx.xx:80,xxx.xx.xxx.xx:80,xxx.xx.xxx.xx:80)
Annotations:                   cloud.google.com/neg: {"ingress": true}
                               kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: false
                               kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce-internal
                               kubernetes.io/ingress.regional-static-ip-name: ingress-internal-static-ip
                               meta.helm.sh/release-name: test-frontend
                               meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Events:
  Type     Reason  Age                 From                     Message
  ----     ------  ----                ----                     -------
  Normal   Sync    113s (x4 over 21m)  loadbalancer-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Warning  Sync    24s (x19 over 18m)  loadbalancer-controller  Error syncing to GCP: error running load balancer syncing routine: loadbalancer z30rnomw-isp-isp-ingress-pjgwvt2i does not exist: invalid configuration: both HTTP and HTTPS are disabled (kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http is false and there is no valid TLS configuration); your Ingress will not be able to serve any traffic
```

Helm Chart fails to add the TLS details in the ingress.yaml. Do I miss something?

Comment: Where are you creating the Secret `ingress-tls-credential-file`?  Looks like the Ingress references it, but does it actually exist?

Comment: Yes. ingress-tls-credential-file exist in the GKE secrets and configmaps. It is created by terraform script. After successful creation only, the helm chart deployment starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, your `values.yaml` is wrong. The `tls` block starts at the wrong indentation. It should be at the same level as the `enabled`, `annotations` and `hosts` i.e. at the first level after `ingress`.

Comment: I have fixed the indentation also.... Still facing the same issue. Updated values.yaml here.

Comment: Kindly share the snippet to fix the TLS entry

Comment: I removed my original comment. The template ignores fields that it does not know about. However, `secretType` would anyway be wrong so removing it is a good idea in any case. You should print the ingress that was generated to ensure that the correct secret is used for the `tls` entry.

Answer (score 0):

I see a custom k8s namespace of `isp`, this namespace will not have access to the TLS cert in any other namespace including the `default` one. You must create the TLS cert in the same k8s namespace your ingress is deployed into.

Comment: Now the helm chart and TLS cert are in same isp namespace, but still ingress fails to read the TLS details